# Restricted Polyglot

Tags: restricted-source, polyglot, rosetta-stone, comment

Polyglots are programs that are valid in multiple programming languages simultaneously. Most such polyglots are written in such a way that certain constructs of one language are interpreted as comments of another language (e.g. `#define` in C being interpreted as a comment in several scripting languages).

I am curious to see if it is possible to make a non-trivial polyglot which contains no comments, but also immediately changes when you remove any non-whitespace character,  I therefore challenge you to come up with such a program.

The concrete rules are as follows:

1. (Output). Your program must produce some output on the console under each of your languages. That is, your program is not permitted to simply exit without printing anything.
2. (Variance). As a relaxation of the standard polyglot definition, the program's output may vary between languages.
3. (Errors). Your program must not produce any errors (broadly defined) under any of your languages. For most languages, this is defined as returning a non-zero exit code from the compiler and/or interpreter.
4. (Restriction). The removal of any single non-whitespace character from your code should cause your program to change its behaviour under *every* one of your languages. The program may "change" by becoming invalid for that language, or by changing the output that is produced.
5. This is a *code challenge*. Winner is the program which is valid in the most programming languages. Ties will be broken in favor of shorter program length.

The restriction rule doesn't apply to the removal of several characters. That is, it is fine if removing several characters simultaneously results in no change for one of your languages.

Observe that the restriction rule implies that you cannot use Whitespace as one of your languages, as removing any non-whitespace character won't change the behaviour of the Whitespace program.

Here's a simple example of a program that fulfills all the above restrictions, for the languages Python 2 and Python 3:

```
print("Hello World!")
```

Removing any character in `print` will cause both languages to throw a `NameError`; removing any bracket or quote will throw a `SyntaxError`, and removing any of the string characters will change the output in both languages. (Note that `print("hello", "world")` is a more subtle, but still valid program under the above rules).

This example is a bit lame because Python 2 and Python 3 are very similar, so I won't accept any other solutions that only use different versions of the same language (especially Python 2 and Python 3).

Comment: @IngoBürk: The rule prevents you from writing a functional polyglot which involves Whitespace, unless somehow your *other* language is also whitespace-only.

Comment: FWIW your example, `print("Hello World!")` is also valid Ruby code

Comment: It's a little annoying that the simple answers (like mine) to a [polyglot] tend to be able to have so many languages.

Comment: To avoid the myriad language variants or languages with similar syntax, it would be more interesting to require that two languages count as different only if the program produces different output.

Answer (score 13):

## Bash + GolfScript + CJam

```
"echo" []
{ cat<&3;} \
3<""<("echo" 'p'~)
```

#### Output

Bash:

```
[]
p~
```

GolfScript:

```
"echo"
echo{ cat<&3;}0
```

CJam:

```
echo{ cat<&3;}-1echop
```

There is a `\x7f` in the end of output of CJam.

Comment: ...wait, how does this work in all three languages, without being redundant?

Comment: @nneonneo It simply prints all the unused code in other languages.

Answer (score 9):

## Bash + Befunge

```
"echo" $,$,"ol":,,,@
```

prints 'hello' in befunge.

Comment: I can attest that every character (except the space) does something in Befunge. I can't do so for the Bash though. This is impressive.

Answer (score 7):

## GolfScript + PHP + CJam + Mathematica + bc + Pyth + [///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////) + TI-Basic + R + Octave + Matlab + Scilab + [Numeric Topline](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Numeric_Topline) + ?[Fueue](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fueue) + [huh?](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Huh)

```
10
```

In Golscript, PHP, CJam, Mathematica, bc, Pyth, ///, and TI-Basic, it outputs `10`.

In R, it outputs `[1] 10`

In Octave, it outputs `ans =  10`

In Matlab and Scilab, it outputs `ans = 10`.

In Numeric Topline, it outputs `0`.

If I understand Fueue properly, it outputs a newline, then acts as a cat program.

In huh?, it outputs

```
What?
?
```

Comment: Also works in CJam

Comment: I don't think interactive interpreters should count.

Comment: This runs fine in a lot of languages, but doesn't provide output in that many...

Comment: This is also valid in *HTML*, *bc*, *Matlab* and *Scilab*. If you change `72` to `10`, it should print `0` in [Numeric Topline](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Numeric_Topline).

Comment: HTML is not a programming language according to the meta discussion as it has no means of simple arithmetic or loops.

Comment: bc prints `10` on my machine. Matlab and Scilab prints `ans = 10` (and possibly some whitespace).

Comment: And in mathematica it should output `10`

Comment: Outputs 10 in Pyth

Comment: It also seems to be valid in [///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////).

Comment: Should work in Javascript too..

Comment: @TejasKale That only works in a JavaScript interpreter, such as the Chrome Console. But the standard for this website is that JavaScript needs to be wrapped in `alert` for it to be valid. Same with Python, we aren't allowed to simply post `10` as a quine in Python.

Comment: This does "work" in nodejs, but prints nothing(same for python). Reading the rules again, I see why these languages were not included.

Comment: TI-BASIC it outputs 10.

Comment: @IngoBürk HTML + CSS is turing complete and therefore can perform arithmetic, (it essentially can emulate rule 110)

Answer (score 7):

## bc, GolfScript, Homespring, huh, Octave, Scilab (0 bytes)

Guaranteed to comply with rule 4. Not a winner, but would do well in the tie break.

#### Output

bc

```
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'.
```

GolfScript

Homespring

```
In Homespring, the null program is not a quine.
```

huh

```
?
```

Octave

```
GNU Octave, version 3.6.4
Copyright (C) 2013 John W. Eaton and others.
This is free software; see the source code for copying conditions.
There is ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  For details, type `warranty'.

Octave was configured for "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".

Additional information about Octave is available at http://www.octave.org.

Please contribute if you find this software useful.
For more information, visit http://www.octave.org/get-involved.html

Read http://www.octave.org/bugs.html to learn how to submit bug reports.

For information about changes from previous versions, type `news'.
```

Scilab

```
Startup execution:
  loading initial environment

-->
```

Comment: I know there's an esolang which specifically prevents 0 length quines by doing this sort of thing (oh wait, that's [Homespring](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Homespring)). I believe [huh?](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Huh) outputs something.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, I can't convince huh? to run on Linux...

Comment: Sadly, I deleted the interpreter from my computer, and I can't download the interpreter on this network.

Comment: All I needed was an extra package for mono. Your program prints `What?\n?`, by the way.

Comment: Also works in GNU Make (if that's a programming language): `make: *** No targets.  Stop.`

Comment: @user23013: Makefiles are Turing complete, so I'd say yes. Thanks! (The output is entirely different on my system.)

Comment: @Dennis The correct way running a file called `polyglot` should be `make -f polyglot`. Or you can simply rename that file to `Makefile` and then `make`.

Comment: @user23013: Right. In that case, it's not a valid entry, since make's exit code is 2.

Comment: @Dennis Ah... `make -f polyglot some_existed_file` works, but I don't think that should qualify...

Comment: Also works in Guile, at least if you pipe it in on standard input; my version prints a prompt and then exits. Apparently it can't tell that it isn't being used interactively.

Answer (score 3):

> Seems like this answer is not fully correct.
>   I partially fixed it, and going to improve the other part in a few days.

## C++ & Javascript

### The idea is:

```
void eval(bool="main=function(){alert('Hi from Javascript!')};puts=function(){};int=0");
int
main()
{
puts("Hi from C++!");
}
```

C++: http://codepad.org/SK2wbIDL
Javascript: Just copy code to the browser console

### And a set of fixes to make it satisfy

> (Restriction). The removal of any single non-whitespace character from your code should cause your program to change its behaviour under every one of your languages. The program may "change" by becoming invalid for that language, or by changing the output that is produced.

#### From Javascript side:

Changing `int`, `main` or `puts` will crash with reading of undeclared variable. But `bool` and `Hi from C++!` can be safely changes. Let's fix it:

```
puts=function(){}
```

```
puts=function(s){s=='Hi from C++!'?bool:nope}
```

If strings are equal, it checks existance of `bool`, otherwice it crashes with undeclared `nope`.

Now, there are 2 trailing semicolons that can be removed. The first is fixed esyly - just remove newline before `int`:

```
void eval(bool="main=function(){alert('Hi from Javascript!')};puts=function(){};int=0");int
```

The second is before `}`, so I need some constriction, valid in both languages and not requiring semicolon at the end in C++ or forsing a semicolon in js. Fine:

```
while(0);
```

It's impossible to omit semicolon in js as `while` needs the body.

So the program at the moment is:

```
void eval(bool="main=function(){alert('Hi from Javascript!')};puts=function(s){s=='Hi from C++!'?bool:nope};int=0");int
main()
{
puts("Hi from C++!");while(0);
}
```

#### From C++ side:

There are 2 problems: `eval` can have any name and all js code can be changed.

*I'll try to fix them in a few days.*

Answer (score 2):

## CJam + Golfscript

Okay, this is somewhat boring, but it's a start.

```
1,
```

Prints "0" in both languages. Removal of the `1` causes an error, removing the `,` prints "1" instead.

The same can be done with `1)` or `1(`. There are many alternatives.

(Yes, I know this isn't code-golf)

Answer (score 2):

## C and C++

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { puts("Hello!"); return 0; }
```

C and C++ are different languages that are almost compatible with each other - contrary to what you might hear C++ is not a superset of C.  Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B for some differences.  The example above is not idiomatic C++ but it does work and produces the same output in both C and C++.

Comment: You can remove the `0` for C.

Comment: @Dennis Not in C89.

Comment: @Gilles: *If the main function executes a return that specifies no value, the termination status returned to the host environment is undefined.* ([The C89 Draft - 2.1.2.2 Hosted environment](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#2.1.2.2)) That doesn't make the program invalid nor does it change its output, so for the purposes of this question, the `0` can be removed.

Comment: @Dennis I think an unspecified exit code counts as making the program invalid as per the rules of this question. If it doesn't, make that a C89 implementation where this program returns a nonzero exit code, such as `gcc -ansi` on x86 (or many other architectures: what happens is that the return value of `puts` ends up being in the register where the runtime reads the value to return from the `main` function).

Comment: @Gilles: My interpretation of rule 3 is that the compiler must return 0, not the program.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScipt, Lua, R and Python 3 - 24 bytes

May work on some other languages, I'll test latter.

```
alert=print;alert(1)
```

JavaScript was tested on Firefox's console and the other languages [here](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_lua_online.php), [here](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_r_online.php) and [here](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python3_online.php)

Comment: This does *not* work in Javascript. It shows the print dialog.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl + Ruby + Python

I think in PHP this would need a semicolon if you are running with `-R`.

```
print "Hello World!"
```

Comment: This works in Python as well.

Comment: Also works with Lua.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + sh + zsh + ksh, 4 bytes:

```
echo
```

Really simple and satisfies every rule:

1. Outputs a newline in each of the languages.
2. Output currently does *not* vary in any way between the languages.
3. Does not produce an error in any of the languages...
4. ...*except* when any of the characters are removed/changed.

Answer (score 0):

## Bash + sh + zsh + ksh + Windows Batch, 4 bytes:

```
echo
```

Really simple and satisfies every rule:

Outputs a newline which doesn't vary in each of the languages (but Windows Batch, which outputs `ECHO is on`, on the language you use), doesn't error, except when any letter is removed or changed.

Comment: Your answer appears to be almost identical to this one: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100654/65326

Answer (score 0):

## Every single flavor of HQ9+, 1 byte

```
9
```

Including but not limited to HQ9+, FishQ9+, BrainfishQ9+, CHIQRSX9+, Unified HQ9+, H9+, HQ9++,HQ9+-, FHQ9+-, HQ9F+, HQ9+B, HQ9+~, HQ9+2D, HI9+, and probably some more that I've missed.